# join two tables with different rows and multiple select statements

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a result as

```
select D.name as username, E.maxViews AS EmaxViews from (select A.video_id, A.uploaded_by AS username,max(B.numViews) AS maxViews,count(*) AS C from Videos A, (select video,count(*) AS numViews from Views GROUP BY video) B where A.video_id=B.video GROUP BY A.uploaded_by) E, Users D where D.username=E.username
```

which gives me the columns as `username,EmaxViews` and gives me 93 rows

and I have another table as `Users (username,date_registered,name)` which has 100 queries in it

I would like to join my above two queries as a single table as

```
username, date_registered, EmaxViews
```

I tried like this

```
select name, date_registered,G.EmaxViews from Users F LEFT OUTER JOIN (select D.name as username, E.maxViews AS EmaxViews from (select A.video_id, A.uploaded_by AS username,max(B.numViews) AS maxViews,count(*) AS C from Videos A, (select video,count(*) AS numViews from Views GROUP BY video) B where A.video_id=B.video GROUP BY A.uploaded_by) E, Users D where D.username=E.username) G ON F.username=G.username ORDER BY F.date_registered;
```

Now I am getting 100 rows and proper values for name and date_registered but I am getting NULL for EmaxViews for all the rows..

whats wrong in my query ?

Comment: Can you give us samples from the tables you are looking to read from?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  u.name AS username,
        u.date_registered,
        COALESCE
                (
                (
                SELECT  COUNT(*) cnt
                FROM    video v
                JOIN    views vw
                ON      vw.video = v.video_id
                WHERE   v.uploaded_by = u.name
                GROUP BY
                        v.video_id
                ORDER BY
                        cnt DESC
                LIMIT 1
                ),
                0
                ) AS EmaxViews
FROM    users u
```

Comment: no.. I am sorry.. I was giving wrong column names in the second query.. I solved it.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

no.. I am sorry.. I was giving wrong column names in the second query.. I solved it.. thanks